# PHP - Break out of an if statement

Tags: php

So I have this code which assigns different variables depending on if a file exists or not:

```
$progress_file_path = './data/progress.txt';

if (file_exists($progress_file_path) && count($scanned) > 0) {
    $scanned = file($progress_file_path);
    $last = end($scanned);
    $end = $limit + count($scanned);
}
else { 
    $last = 'unset'; 
    $end = $limit;
}
```

but I need to do more with this, I need to make sure the file has content in it. I do the check in the conditional like this:

```
if (file_exists($progress_file_path) && count(file($scanned)) > 0)
```

because the `$scanned` variable hasn't been defined yet. So the ideal solution would be if I can break out of the if statement, and jump to the `else` part of the conditional.

Something like this:

```
$progress_file_path = './data/progress.txt';

if (file_exists($progress_file_path)) {
    $scanned = file($progress_file_path);

    if (count($scanned) > 0) { break; }

    $last = end($scanned);
    $end = $limit + count($scanned);

}I 
else { 
    $last = 'unset'; 
    $end = $limit;
}
```

but that doesn't work, you can't break or continue out of an if statement. I was thinking maybe using `goto` to jump into the `else` part of the conditional but I doubt that will work either. Is there a way to jump to the else part of a conditional like this?

Comment: `$progress_file_path = './data/progress.txt';

if (file_exists($progress_file_path)) {
    $scanned = file($progress_file_path);

    if (count($scanned) > 0) { 
  $last = 'unset'; 
     $end = $limit;
    }else{
      $last = end($scanned);
     $end = $limit + count($scanned);
    }

}`

Comment: SelfDecode Support  check the answers and mark one as accepted answer. You can up-vote others too, if they are useful in future.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refining Anant answer

```
$progress_file_path = './data/progress.txt';
$last = 'unset'; 
$end = $limit;
if (file_exists($progress_file_path)) {
    $scanned = file($progress_file_path);
    if (count($scanned) < 0) { 
        $last = end($scanned);
        $end = $limit + count($scanned);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check both of your conditions in one if statement to have at least one else like this

```
$progress_file_path = './data/progress.txt';

if (file_exists($progress_file_path) && count(file($progress_file_path)) > 0) {
    $scanned = file($progress_file_path);

    $last = end($scanned);
    $end = $limit + count($scanned);
} else {
    $last = 'unset'; 
    $end = $limit;
}
```

Comment: But if the file $progress_file_path (progress.txt) doesn't exist, then it gives me a warning or error when I try to open it with file()

Comment: That's right but it shouldn't check it if the file doesn't exists. If the file doesn't exists the first condition of the if is false and it goes to the else